# Oracle sql query to group two sets of dates if sequencials

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I have the next table:

| EMPLOYEE | CODE | START_DATE | END_DATE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 02097368 | F7H3 | 09/07/2018 | 20/10/2018 |
| 02097368 | F7H3 | 21/10/2018 | 05/01/2019 |
| 02097368 | F7H3 | 06/01/2019 | 12/01/2019 |
| 02097368 | F7H3 | 13/01/2019 | 02/02/2019 |
| 02097368 | F7H3 | 03/02/2019 | 13/04/2019 |
| 02097368 | F7S3 | 14/04/2019 | 04/01/2020 |
| 02097368 | F7S3 | 05/01/2020 | 24/03/2020 |
| 02097368 | F7S3 | 31/01/2021 |  |

I would like to group the data by employee, code and sequencial date(end_date to the next start_date if its 1 day later)

DESIRED RESULT:

| EMPLOYEE | CODE | START_DATE | END_DATE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 02097368 | F7H3 | 09/07/2018 | 13/04/2019 |
| 02097368 | F7S3 | 14/04/2019 | 24/03/2020 |
| 02097368 | F7S3 | 31/01/2021 |  |

Im trying this but im not getting the desired result

```
SELECT EMPLOYEE,
       CODE,
       MIN (START_DATE) AS START_DATE,
       MAX (END_DATE)
          KEEP (DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY END_DATE DESC NULLS FIRST)
          AS END_DATE
  FROM (SELECT T.*,
               ROW_NUMBER ()
                  OVER (PARTITION BY EMPLOYEE ORDER BY START_DATE)
                  AS seqnum_i,
               ROW_NUMBER ()
               OVER (PARTITION BY EMPLOYEE, CODE ORDER BY START_DATE)
                  AS seqnum_ir
          FROM CODE_HIST T
         WHERE EMPLOYEE= '02097368') T
GROUP BY ID_EMPLEADO, (seqnum_i - seqnum_ir), CODE;
```

ACTUAL RESULT:

| EMPLOYEE | CODE | START_DATE | END_DATE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 02097368 | F7H3 | 09/07/2018 | 13/04/2019 |
| 02097368 | F7S3 | 14/04/2019 |  |

Comment: So you mean "if ROW N has a start date that is one day after ROW N-1, treat the two rows as one/as if the date range was continuous?

Comment: exactly, starting a new row only when the either the CODE is different or the date range isn´t continuous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this with the following query though I know it's not the most elegant one. Do replace TABLE_1 for the actual table name or view that holds your data

When running the following, I retrieved the below results

```
SELECT EMPLOYEE, CODE, MIN(START_DATE), MAX(END_DATE) FROM 
(
     SELECT EMPLOYEE, CODE, START_DATE, END_DATE, CASE
     WHEN (TEMP1=1 OR TEMP2=1) THEN 'ONE_CLASS'
     ELSE 'OTHER' END  CLASS_X
     FROM            
                (SELECT EMPLOYEE, CODE, 
                START_DATE, END_DATE,
                X AS TEMP1, LEAD(X) OVER (ORDER BY START_DATE) AS TEMP2
                            FROM (
                            SELECT EMPLOYEE, CODE,  
                            LAG(END_DATE) OVER (ORDER BY START_DATE) AS PREV_PERIOD_END_DATE, 
                            START_DATE, END_DATE,
                            START_DATE - LAG(END_DATE) OVER (ORDER BY START_DATE) AS X
                            FROM TABLE_2
                            ORDER BY START_DATE) A
                            ) B
                            ) C
GROUP BY EMPLOYEE, CODE, CLASS_X
ORDER BY MIN(START_DATE)
```

Results:

[image]

Results in text form that I don't know how to format as a table:

EMPLOYEE    CODE    MIN(START_DATE) MAX(END_DATE)
02097368    F7H3    09-JUL-18   13-APR-19
02097368    F7S3    14-APR-19   24-MAR-20
02097368    F7S3    31-JAN-21    -

Comment: That looks like it would produce 2 rows, not the 3 that the questioner is looking for.

Comment: yes you are right! apologies, will amend this now